# Authorize users based on roles in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I would like to authorize users based on few roles. All visitors should be able to reach method show. So I wrote in AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    $this->Auth->allow(['show']);
}
```

It works.

In initialize() method of AppController I've got also:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authorize' => 'Controller'
]);
```

I would like to allow logged users with role "user" to reach all "index", and "add" methods, so I wrote in AppController:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
return true;
}
if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'user') {
$this->Auth->allow(['index', 'logout', 'add']);
}

return false;
}
```

Admin can reach all methods as expected. User logged with role "user" can't reach "index" or "add" method. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could look into [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) as it solves this without having to write code in your controllers :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using your logic to add additional Auth allows, just use the logic to determine if they're in an action they're allowed, by checking the action, and return `true` if they're authorized.

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {

    // Admin allowed anywhere
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // 'user' allowed in specific actions
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'user') {

        $allowedActions = ['index', 'logout', 'add'];
        if(in_array($this->request->action, $allowedActions)) {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

(obviously this code could be shortened to your liking, but it shows the concept)

Comment: Hey, I still can't vote, but your answer helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution to be great and easier to maintain.

```
//in all controllers that you want to restrict access
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    //an array since we might want to add additional roles
    $possibleRoles = array('admin');
    return $this->confirmAuth($user['role'], $possibleRoles);
}

//in AppController
public function confirmAuth($userRole, $allowedRoles)
{
    return in_array($userRole, $allowedRoles);
}
```